# magento 1.9 list.phtml file for category view: view products even if subcategories exist?

Tags: php, magento, product

At the moment, if a category has products in it, it shows a list of products, which is great. However, if a category has a set of products & subcategories in it, it only shows the subcategories rather than the products.

If a category has products and subcategories in it, I want magento to list the products to the user rather than the subcategories in the main viewing space, as it is already showing a list of subcategories on the sidebar.

This is my current list.phtml: https://bpaste.net/show/66110a7264bc

What would I have to do to the list.phtml to have it prioritize showing products? Let's say I have a category that has 5 products and 5 subcategories. The subcategories already show on the side, so I'd like it to show a list of the products in the category.

I am thinking for the first line,

```
<?php if (count($subCatIds) > 1) { ?>
```

Should be something related to if the products is < 1, show the list of subcategories. So I made it say

```
    <?php if (count($productCollection) < 1) { ?>
```

My thought process was, if the number of products is 0, then show the subcategories, but it is not working out that way.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please send your demo website url?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem by this way (if you know exactly where to show only subcategories, products or both):

1.The category edit page in the Magento admin panel has the tab 'Display Settings' and the fields 'Display Mode' and 'CMS Block'. 
If you choose the 'Products only' mode the only products will be displayed on the category page.
If you choose the 'Static block only'mode the only chosen in the 'CMS Block' field static block will be displayed on the category page.
If you choose the 'Static block and products' Magento will show both: static block will be the first, products list - the second.

You may find the logic in the catalog/category/view.phtml

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2.You may create a CMS Block with the subcategories of current category, set it to the 'CMS Block' field and choose the option of the 'Display Mode' you need for the current category.

Or

1.You may try to add the condition to the logic in the catalog/category/view.phtml - if the current category has products:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addCategoryFilter($category)
```

Or

1.Add elseif to the condition to list.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_categoryCollection) : ?>
...
<?php elseif (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
...
<?php else: ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

2.The `$_categoryCollection` is:

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
            ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategory->getEntityId())
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->load();
```

If the solution doesn't fit, please, show the code of the list.phtml (your link returns 404), catalog/category/view.phtml, and the way you are displaying subcategories.